# Saiku Widget shows No Data

Tags: pentaho-cde, saiku

I am using Pentaho CDE and I am trying to put a Saiku analysis file inside the dashboard using Saiku Widget.

However I am getting **No Data** message on the screen and in the browser console I am getting an error **401 - Bad Credentials**.

When I access the Saiku URL directly from the browser, I am getting JSON response. It is not working with-in pentaho CDE dashboard.

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You must edit the file /biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/saiku/ui/js/saiku/embed/SaikuEmbed.js and then restart bi-server, because the content of this file is minified in CDF.js

In this SaikuEmbed.js the user and password are set in

```
var _settings = {
    server: '/saiku',
    path: '/rest/saiku/embed',
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'admin',
    blockUI: false
};
```

but i don't have user admin with password admin, so when it's try to do a verification before ajax call it stack with 401 authorization required.

I modified

```
beforeSend: function(request) {
    if (self.settings.user && self.settings.password) {
        var auth = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(
           self.settings.user + ':' + self.settings.password
        );
       request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
       return true;
    }
},
```

with

```
beforeSend: function(request) {
    if (Dasboards.context.user) {
       return true;
    }
},
```

You can comment all beforeSend, if you want.